# Accessing Values From Object property that is an array

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties

How can I access values from an object property that is an array?

For example:

```
$myObject = new MyClass;

$myObject->myproperty = array(1 => 'English', 2 => 'French', 3 => 'German');
```

How can I get individual property values using the array keys from `$myObject->mypropery`? Using `$myObject->myproperty[3]` does not work.

**EDIT:** Using `$myObject->myproperty[3]` does in fact work.  Where I find a problem is when doing it like this:

```
$myproperty = 'myproperty';

echo $myObject->$myproperty[3]

// result : 'r'
```

Yet if I do a var_dump on `$myObject->$myproperty` I see my array.

Comment: `$myObject->$myProperty` will take the value from `$myProperty` and use it as the property name.  So if `$myProperty = 'foo';`, then it would be the same as saying `$myObject->foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your `myproperty` array values try this:

```
$myObject->{$myproperty}[3]
```

Instead of:

```
$myObject->$myproperty[3]
```

These are referred to as Variables Variable, for more information visit: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

The reason your `echo` result was `r` is because your `$mypropery` value is `mypropery` and you executed this `echo $myObject->$myproperty[3]` which translate to saying you want the third character array keys value. Since arrays are zero based this means you will get the character `r` as a result. Hope this clears up why your result was `r`.

Comment: Yes, I understood that's exactly why I was getting 'r'.  Your answer is entirely correct. I had tried the same previously, but due to some other logical error it didn't work.   Have tried again and it does.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$myObject->myproperty[3]
```

instead of this:

```
$myObject->$myproperty[3]
```

Comment: Naturally, I already answered that, however this is for a behavior that can apply to a multitude of classes, thus $myObject->$myProperty is essential

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = $myObject->$myproperty;
echo $tmp[1];
//or
echo $myObject->{$myproperty}[1];
```